# Add calculated column with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Trying to add a calculated column where another column = 0, however, I'm not sure how to get around the error

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list

along with

> Window functions can only appear in...

I'm essentially only trying to generate a weighted value for records where Source_Value is not 0.

What I have:

```
CREATE TABLE #CURRENT_INPUT (
    ShipYear INT,
    Group_Name VARCHAR(20),
    Total_Count INT,
    Source_Value INT,
);

INSERT INTO #CURRENT_INPUT(ShipYear,Group_Name,Total_Count,Source_Value)
VALUES
      ('2011','TestA','5','3'),
      ('2011','TestA','5','1'),
      ('2011','TestA','5','2'),
      ('2011','TestA','5','2'),
      ('2012','TestC','5','2'),
      ('2012','TestC','5','1'),
      ('2012','TestC','5','0'),
      ('2012','TestC','5','7')


ALTER TABLE #CURRENT_INPUT
    ADD Calc_Values varchar(55)

UPDATE #CURRENT_INPUT
SET Calc_Values = CASE
                      WHEN Source_Value <> 0 
                          THEN ISNULL(SUM(total_count) / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(total_count)) OVER (PARTITION BY ShipYear, group_name), 0), 0) 
                          ELSE Source_Value 
                  END;
```

Desired output (keeping it simple) table would like this:

| ShipYear | Group_Name | Total_Count | Calc_Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 0.25 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 0.33 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 0.33 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 0.0 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 0.33 |

My only other thought is to create a copy of the main table with source_value=0 records excluded and then join this calculated column back to the main table. I was hoping for a cleaner approach, as the main table is quite large with an extensive number of columns.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use `varchar(55)` for a numerical value?

Comment: @DaleK could you provide an example of what you mean by select into update?

Also, I can change the column definition to numeric(10,3) or some version

Comment: @DaleK I've added a minimum reproducible example and a table example of desired column value outcome.

Comment: @DaleK the sum of the row value/sum of the combined row values for any rows with the same ShipYear and Group_Name. Trying to find % of total "group".

Refer to the partition step in the code

Comment: What you explain sounds like `Total_Count/sum over partition` why I was confused is you wrote `sum(Total_Count)/sum over partition` i.e. you had a sum on the top line which doesn't fit your description and it the main cause of your error.

Comment: What happens if total_count is different for a given shipyear and group name? Or is that not possible? If it is possible, please add example and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with your attempt:

- You were getting over enthusiastic with your `SUM`s - take a layer of `SUM`s out (I also removed null checks because they don't normally affects sums but you might need to add them back).
- You need your conditional `CASE` expression to be inside the `SUM` not outside it.
- Also need to force the values to decimal to avoid integer division.

```
CASE
    WHEN Source_Value <> 0 
    THEN CONVERT(decimal(9,2),Total_Count*1.0 / SUM(CASE WHEN Source_Value > 0 THEN Total_Count ELSE 0 END*1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY ShipYear, Group_Name))
    ELSE Source_Value
END
```

Returns for the data provided:

| ShipYear | Group_Name | Total_Count | Source_Value | Calc_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 3 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 2 | 0.25 |
| 2011 | TestA | 5 | 2 | 0.25 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 2 | 0.33 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 1 | 0.33 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 2012 | TestC | 5 | 7 | 0.33 |

And this can then be simply converted into an UPDATE one way is using a CTE e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , CASE
            WHEN Source_Value <> 0 
            THEN CONVERT(decimal(9,2),Total_Count*1.0 / SUM(CASE WHEN Source_Value > 0 THEN Total_Count ELSE 0 END*1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY ShipYear, Group_Name))
            ELSE Source_Value
        END NewCalc_Value
    FROM #CURRENT_INPUT
)
UPDATE cte SET Calc_Value = NewCalc_Value;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/umrroTgS)

Comment: Thank you, I will test this on the larger dataset and circle back.

Comment: worked great! I just had to add a nullif() on the divisor side of the equation and overcome the "arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric". Seemed to work when I set the calc_values to numeric(30,15) and the decimal to (18,0). thanks for your help!

Comment: `numeric(30,15)` has 15 digits after the decimal point? Seems a few more than you need.

Comment: I was running into the "arithmetic overflow" warning, it seems at the point where we're setting Calc_Value=NewCalc_Value

Answer (score -1):

Use an update with join to the calculation:

```
update t
set Calc_Values = iif(Source_Value = 0, 0.0, calc)
from #CURRENT_INPUT t
join (
select
  ShipYear,
  Group_Name,
  convert(decimal(4,2), 1 / sum(iif(Source_Value = 0, 0.0, 1.0))) as calc
from #CURRENT_INPUT
group by ShipYear, Group_Name
) c on c.ShipYear = t.ShipYear
  and c.Group_Name = t.Group_Name
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IC5bCo1b).

Note that using a join means you only need to do one pass over the table to calculate values for all rows.

Note also that using `iif()` is more readable than `case when ... then ... else ... end`

Comment: Thats subject to opinion :) think you want `iif(Source_Value = 0, 0.0, Total_Value)` otherwise there is an assumption that `Total_Count` is the same for all rows.